# Command-line interface for Computer Managment MMC?

Tags: command-line-interface, windows

I want to make a script that closes open files in our storage.

I can do it with `compmgmt.msc`, connecting to the storage as a remote computer, then I go to "System Tools" --> "Shared Folders" --> "Open Files".

Is there a Command-line interface for Computer Managment MMC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `openfiles` command line works in the same way. You can use it without argument to get a list of open files (sadly, the tool is hard-coded to truncate the output so it might be a bit touch and go if you have long file path).

You can then use the `openfiles /disconnect (file)` command to disconnect a specific file.

Edit: you can do better with [powershell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/67e94a6a-47e8-420a-b28a-759d876fb15e/how-to-list-open-files-using-powershell).